# Array VS Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a class that goes something like:

```
class node{// case 1
    float points[maxCap][d];
    ...
}
```

I can also do it like:

```
class node{// case 2
    float** points;

    node(){
        points = (float**)malloc(maxCap*sizeof(float*));
        if(points)
            for(int i=0; i<maxCapacity; i++)
                points[i] = (float*)malloc(d*sizeof(float));
        else{
            cout<<"Unable to get memory"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

They are basically nodes in a tree. I'm creating approximately 500'000 to 1'000'000 of these.

When I search for a point, with every single thing in the search algorithm being the same, case 2 comes out to be approximately 0.2 seconds slower than case 1 (taking average over 3 runs -- although the times are more or less the same for all the 3 runs). Time for case 1 is approx `0.88s` while that for case 2 is approx `1.07s`. Can someone please tell me what's going on here? Shouldn't this be approximately the same?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208575/discussion-on-question-by-ankit-kumar-array-vs-pointers).

Comment: Please don't allocate memory in that way.  If you want a 2D array, and for whatever reason you want to allocate it "by hand", and the number of columns is uniform, then [this is much better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048) for a whole host of reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't provide the code that does the actual searching. But, assuming that the search actually needs to access the data within/behind `points`, the problem is clear:

- With the array, the data is stored right in the `node` object, and simple pointer arithmetic is performed to deduce the location of `points[a][b]`. **Only a single memory access is needed to actually fetch the value from memory.**
- With the pointer approach, the node only contains the address of where an array of addresses is stored. So, `points` loads a pointer value from memory, `points[a]` loads a second pointer value from memory, and `points[a][b]` finally loads the actual value into the CPU, ready to be compared. **That's three memory accesses where a single one sufficed in the array case.**

Even if your cache and prefetching does a good job at mitigating the impact of the extra memory accesses, a single memory access easily outperforms three.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider `points[1][2]`.

There are twice as many pointers followed with `float** points;` than `float points[10][3];`.

As a sketch, it is:

```
float* inner = *(points + 1);
float result = *(inner + 2);
```

As opposed to

```
float result = *(points + (3 * 2) + (1));
```